# npm run build not including all the files

Tags: reactjs, deployment, web-deployment

I am new in ReactJs. This is my first try to develop and deploy on server.

I have done few pages and wanted to display this project on subdomain so my client can have a track. To deploy on a server I built it using `npm run build`. This works successfully. I deploy a code on a server. But It is displaying just a index or home page. I guess it is not building inside pages. How can we do that?

Here is my file structure -

```
src --
-------- component --
--------------------- element
--------------------- common
--------------------- footer
--------------------- header
-------- elements --
--------------------- /*-- Inside Page jsx files --*/
-------- Home
--------------------- /*-- Home Page --*/
```

How to include all the files under `src` folder in build? It is working properly on local server. Also, I tried with `server -s build` and it is working fine as well. But it is not working on server. Is it because I am deploying on subdomain or there is any other necessary steps that I have to do?

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so basically routing is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually occurs because of your hosting service provider is not supporting node.js. Please check with your hosting service provider.

If they are not supporting node.js then you can try with [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

This will help you to upload your code on server and just redirect to your domain point.

You can check this video - [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUW5GAFhu6s) fot deployment and some basics.

Check out [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/reference) for more information.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is building inside pages but when you want to show them , you must use other Components in index.js inside the ReactDOM.render().
Do you set it?

```js
ReactDOM.render(     
  <Element />,
  <Common />,
  <Header />,
  <Footer />,
  document.getElementById('Help-modal')        
);
```